# PHP | if stament always false

Tags: php

I have a small problem with an if loop, I am building an appointment booking area, the directives are:

- Appointments can be made from Monday to Friday
- Appointment times: 11:00 - 13:00 and 15:00 - 18:00

the variables that take the value from the datepicker and timepicker are:

datepicker:

```
$app_to_data = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['data']);
```

timepicker:

```
$app_to_orario = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['orario']);
```

no problem to prevent the chosen day from being confirmed when the user chooses to book an appointment on Saturday or Sunday:

```
if(date('w', strtotime($app_to_data)) == 6 || date('w', strtotime($app_to_data)) == 0) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var errore_appto = "<?php echo $id_pa ?>";
        window.location = "prendi_appto_errore.php?errore_appto=" + errore_appto;
    </script>
<?php
exit;
}
```

the problem now comes when I have to initiate if cycles to check the time slot chosen for the appointment:

```
   /*VERIFICA CHE L' APPUNTAMENTO NON VENGA PRESO PRIMA DELLE ORE 11:00*/
    if($app_to_orario < '11:00'){
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var errore_appto = "<?php echo $id_pa ?>";
            window.location = "prendi_appto_errore.php?errore_appto=" + errore_appto;
        </script>
    <?php
    exit;
    }

    /*VERIFICA CHE L' APPUNTAMENTO NON VENGA PRESO DOPO LE ORE 13:00*/
    elseif($app_to_orario > '13:00'){
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var errore_appto = "<?php echo $id_pa ?>";
            window.location = "prendi_appto_errore.php?errore_appto=" + errore_appto;
        </script>
    <?php
    exit;
    }


    /*VERIFICA CHE L' APPUNTAMENTO NON VENGA PRESO PRIMA DELLE ORE 15:00*/
    elseif($app_to_orario < '15:00'){
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var errore_appto = "<?php echo $id_pa ?>";
            window.location = "prendi_appto_errore.php?errore_appto=" + errore_appto;
        </script>
    <?php
    exit;
    }


    /*VERIFICA CHE L' APPUNTAMENTO NON VENGA PRESO DOPO LE ORE 18:00*/
    elseif($app_to_orario > '18:00'){
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var errore_appto = "<?php echo $id_pa ?>";
            window.location = "prendi_appto_errore.php?errore_appto=" + errore_appto;
        </script>
    <?php
    exit;
    }
```

the problem I have is that if for example the user chooses to book an appointment for 16:00, the chosen time is correct, but I always get an error because for example in the second cycle 16:00 it is greater than 13:00 even if it falls correctly in the remaining 3 control cycles, so how do I perform a time check allowing the appointment in the time slots indicated in the question, without always running into a false result?

Comment: String comparison `$str < '15:00'` is error prone. Here kicks in string comparison or even possibly int's conversion. Better off to convert your time to some int. E.g. `15:45` => `1545` and then compare

Comment: You need to combine your checks to cope with the two appointment periods - `if $app < "11:00" or ($app >"13:00" and $app < "15:00") or $app > "18:00"` it's not valid, otherwise it is.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, *$app_to_orario* is a string, not a DateTime. To compare with other date/time, it needs to be converted to DateTime first:

```
$ato = new DateTime($app_to_orario);
```

Or use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/):

```
$ato = new Carbon($app_to_orario);
```

Then compare the time(with Carbon):

```
if($ato->hour<11){
    ...
}
```

Or without Carbon:

```
if(intval($ato->format('H'))<11){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
if (str_replace(":", "", $app_to_orario) > str_replace(":", "", "11:00"))
{
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this?